# How to check that string contains is english only

Tags: c#

i have a string which contains values like:

```
string str ="Abhigyan Prakash,Primeshow,NewsPoint,NCP,Inflation,सरकार,राहुल,प्राइम शो,न्यूजप्वाइंट,कमजोर,एनसीपी,अभिज्ञान प्रकाश,Rahul";
```

i have used below code to convert it to array list:

```
    ArrayList altags = new ArrayList( str.Split(','));
```

now i wants to remove all those strings from arraylist which belongs from non-english language (in my context those words which are written in "hindi" should be removed)

please suggest me how to check that string is written in english (with numeric and symbols) or in other language..

NOTE: i have no issue with generic list. i cant take it also. but please tell me how to check that string contains only alphabets + numeric + symbols
Thanks

Comment: What counts as "English"? Only ASCII characters, with no accents etc?

(Why are you using ArrayList, by the way? Any reason you can't use generic collections?)

Comment: Simply do the stuff u used to do in C++ homeworks.. check for the ASCII value cause the Hindi Chars are Unicode Characters.

Comment: wooo.. got it.. thanks plez put it in answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to filter strings with latin symbols, numeric symbols and spaces, you may use regular expressions.

```
        var regex = new Regex("[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*");
        var result = str.Split(',')
                        .Where(s => regex.Match(s).Value == s)
                        .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the [ascii tables](http://www.asciitable.com/) characters of English words (with numeric) should fall between the ranges 48 - 57 (0-9), 65-90 (A-Z) and 97-122 (a-z)

You might want to add to the ranges punctuation signs and other imported characters like é (from fiancé for example).

Comment: got it but what about symbols?

Comment: thats up to you, if you want to detect English you have to compare chars within an accurate range, if you want only to discard Hindi you might want to look up the Hindi range of characters.If you discard any char greater than 255 is a quite possible that you discard Hindi, but also Chinese, Japanese...